# How to launch eclipse from a command line on MacOS with a workspace pathname

Tags: eclipse, macos

On linux:

```
eclipse PathnameToWorkspace
```

works fine, and launches eclipse on the workspace.

I've never been able to figure out the MacOS moral equivalent, given the MacOS application tree structure.

I suspect this is not a hard problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`./eclipse -data <workspace-path>` (see also [How do I run Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F) in the Eclipse Wiki).

Comment: On MacOS, the 'eclipse' in the root is a symlink which points to 'Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse'.  If that symlink doesn't exist, you can create your own or just use that relative path on the command line.

Answer (score -1):

On my system there's a link to the eclipse binary from `/Applications/eclipse/eclipse`, and I find that just running that will start Eclipse with my default workspace.

You might also find the Eclipse binary in '/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse'.

When I start Eclipse like this (from the command line) I find that my Mac will not always switch to the desktop where Eclipse is started, so that I will have to go hunt for the Eclipse window with Exposé/Misson Control (Ctrl-Up Arrow). – This is especially true when I'm have two monitors connected to my Mac.

Since I found typing the full path to eclipse annoying, I simply added a symlink to it from `/opt/local/bin` and made sure that directory is in my `$PATH`:

```
cd /opt/local/bin
sudo ln -s /Applications/eclipse/eclipse .
echo 'PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/bin' >>~/.bashrc
```

After that, just issuing the command `eclipse` (without the preceding `/Applications/eclipse` part) works as it should.

Answer (score -1):

After doing lots of hit and try I have added following into my bash_profile and I am able to launch eclipse from terminal.

(Note: Eclipse is inside Application)

**export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS"**

Hope it will be helpful for beginner like me.