# Eclipse IDE does not start

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

My computer suddenly shut down due to power failure, while I was working on an Android project using my Eclipse Indigo IDE.

Now, if I start Eclipse, only an empty message dialog (see screen shot) appears and Eclipse does not start. What can I do?

(I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried starting eclipse with the -clean parameter?  "eclipse -clean"

Comment: Yes, I tried this option, but no success.

Comment: You may want to consider reporting a bug. Even if Eclipse does not start, it should not display a *blank* message box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse hangs on loading workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972034/eclipse-hangs-on-loading-workbench)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mabe Some files found in the **.metadata** folder of your workspace are damaged, have you tried to launch it by specifying another workspace?

> You can manually specify the workspace location on the command line, using the -data  command-line argument.

If you don't want to loose a lot of time by trying to fix the problem, you can import your projects into the new workspace, reinstall the plugins that was installed before and everything will be ok. otherwise, you have to take a look on the **.log** file found in the **.metadata** folder of your old workspace, analyse the stacktrace and try to understand which plugin is corrupted and delete it manually, and this may take a lot of time, thats why i suggest you the first solution. About the **.metadata** folder, it is in **~old_workspace/.metadata**.

Comment: Of course, if I start by specifying a new workspace, it starts without any problems. What can I do to repair my original workspace? (I cannot locate the .metadata folder in the Ubuntu file system)

Comment: If you don't want to loose a lot of time by trying to fix the problem, you can import your projects into the new workspace, reinstall the plugins that was installed before and everything will be ok. otherwise, you have to take a look on the .log file found in the .metadata folder of your old workspace, analyse the stacktrace and try to understand which plugin is corrupted and delete it manually, and this may take a lot of time, thats why i suggest you the first solution. About the **.metadata** folder, it is in ~old_workspace/.metadata.

Answer (score 1):

1. check your filesystems. Maybe something got corrupted when power was lost.
2. Check my blog post [When Eclipse Won't Start](http://blog.pdark.de/2012/04/13/when-eclipse-wont-start/) and [Restoring a Corrupted Workspace in Eclipse](http://blog.pdark.de/2011/09/02/restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse/)

Comment: Where is actually the .metadata folder located in the Ubuntu file system?

Answer (score 1):

For me, .metadata files were damaged. Since eclipse was not opening at all, changing the workspace was not an option. I deleted following directories, and could start afresh!

1. .metadata
2. .buildpath
3. .project

Hope this helps you as well.
Please note that you will end up loosing all the project settings.

Answer (score 1):

I know my reply is too late. Hope this helps another user.

My Ubuntu in the VMware was shutdown abnormally for some reason. When I logged back in Eclipse would not start. I fixed with the following steps:

1. removed .lock file in the .metadata folder in the workspace
2. started eclipse using command line with "-clean" argument

It started fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the corrupted file by removing the files from `~/workspace/.metadata/` one by one until Eclipse could start.

The corrupted file was `~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap`

Once the file was removed Eclipse started normally.