# Eclipse does not start with particular workspace

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I am facing a problem while starting my Eclipse on ubuntu. I am getting following message when I try to start eclipse using terminal.

> "Job found still running after platform shutdown. Jobs should be
>   canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$Notify Job"

**Eclipse version** : Eclipse Kepler

**OS** : Ubuntu 12.04LTS 32 bit

***I tried***

./eclipse -clean

./eclipse -clean -refresh

rm -r ~/.eclipse

I also deleted .lock file from .metadata folder.

But had no success.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution to this problem, thanks to **Wolfgang Fahl** for his [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16483745/1554935)

> "eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState"

worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

$ rm YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi

Comment: Thnx for your help, however that did not work for me.

Comment: Worked for me! BUT: the whole workspace view configurations will be reset. Just wanted to mention...