# Eclipse won't start up on Mac and stuck on loading screen (Won't respond)

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, command-line, startup

I'm about to lose my mind please help me I've been on this for 4 hours. I do not know how to use the command line well so if anyone explains it using the command line please explain it very throughly.

Every time I load up Eclipse, it doesn't load and I have to force quit it. I tried searching every forums and tried everything and nothing worked. I am trying to use Eclipse C++ version on the Mac. Please if anyone can help me step by step tutorial that would be great.

Comment: Which version of eclipse (Mars/Luna) do you have, which version of Java, and which version of MacOS?

Comment: I installed Java 7 and Java 8. I installed both Mars & Luna but I want to use it for Mars. I'm using OS X El Capitan. Thanks again.

Comment: Also I personally want to use Java 8 (or 1.8 but when I google Java 8, that's the one I downloaded). Also the start up screen pops up with Eclipse but it just doesn't respond and freezes and I have to close it.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it? What else have you tried?

Comment: I've tried reinstalling it, I've tried installing different versions, I've tried this forum as well but did not understand it well.

Comment: I've also tried this.      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972034/eclipse-hangs-on-loading-workbench

Comment: But I couldn't understand it well because I'm not that familiar with the terminal (Command-Line) and every time I tried there methods, it says directory not found ect..

Answer (score 0):

https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/os-x-10-11-beta-3-brakes-eclipse-and-myeclipseide/

Found the answer. The beta version of El Capitan doesn't not work with Eclipse so I have to wait for an update. Thanks everyone for the help!