# Unable to open Eclipse from my user account in Fedora

Tags: eclipse, fedora

Basically i screwed up my previous eclipse installation. I had deleted few folders related to some plugins(which i don't remeber now). After that instance only the Eclipse bootsplash shows up after which i see eclipse in the top bar of gnome shell indicating eclipse has started. But there is no window showing up (or the eclipse window is invisible).

I tried all the methods prescribed here [Eclipse hangs on loading workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972034/eclipse-hangs-on-loading-workbench). Eclipse GUI doesn't show up only in my user account but it works when i load from guest user account.

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse many times. Please can someone help me solve this issue.

PS: Running eclipse from command line doesn't show any exceptions.

Comment: __Q:__ How did you install Eclipse? By the package manager? Or did you just download the zip from [eclipse.org](http://eclipse.org) and unpack it in your home folder and use it?

Comment: __Q:__ Which version of Fedora are you using?

Comment: Hi, I have installed the eclipse using dnf install eclipse. Currently i'm using Fedora 22. I remember deleting some folders related to eclipse in my home directory but i don't remeber the names.

Comment: Normally just deleting eclipse workspace or settings directory, should not stop eclipse from working.

Comment: Also, the Eclipse Splash screen doesn't show any progress bar like loading plugins which it was showing earlier.

Comment: __Q:__ Have you tried to login on the same Fedora machine, as a other user? And checked if that user can still use Eclipse? If not, there is more removed then just some local Eclipse stuff....

Comment: __Q:__ Did you try to start Eclipse in clean mode? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so

Comment: Yes when i login from a different user account on the same machine I am able to run Eclipse without any problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93451/discussion-between-verhagen-and-rudra-murthy).

Comment: @Verhagen Yes i tried running eclipse using clean mode. But even that didn't help.